# JVM run time memory / net beans run time memory /JVM run time memory with arguments (VTD-Parser)

Tags: java, xml, jvm, netbeans-8, vtd-xml

I am parsing a file which is around  `600MB` in size.

Below is memory usage when the file runs

1] When running from Netbeans with `-Xms1g` runtime JVM arguments
   it takes around `1.03GB memory` (checked from Task Manager)

2] When I directly ran `JAR` it took maximum of `1.34GB` (checked from Task Manager) and threw `java outofmemory exception` (I have set my JVM Runtime parameters with `-Xms2048M` also tried with `-Xms1g`)

3] When I run from cmd with JVM arguments `-Xms1g` it takes `1.03GB` memory and gives the proper output.

Question : 
My JVM run time parameters are set to run on 2gb memory (tried 1gb too) why does it throw `outofmemory` even though it gives proper output when the memory is specifically given in the cmd command?

[image]

Comment: In case 2:  How do you run the jar ? Double clicking it ? How do you set the max memory parameters ?

Comment: yes. just double click.

Comment: since I assume that it should directly run in the memory which I have specified in JVM.

Comment: Can you send me the jar file so I can give it a try?

Comment: I can, but it is XML specific and if you dont have an xml with defined codes  you would not be able to test it.

Comment: does your jar app consume additional memory? also tried server or client jvm?

Comment: I dont think that it will consume any additional memory, and no, i havent tried that.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt' appear that this is vtd-xml related issue... you can probably use JProbe to do a heap analysis to determine the cause of memory issue...